# Control reaches end of non void function. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, xcode

How can I fix this issue? What does that error mean? Please explain as I am almost done with this script. I just have to clear that error

```
fraction fraction::print() const
{
int num=numerator;
int den=denominator;
int a = 0;
if(num>den)
{
    for(int counter=2;counter<den;counter++)
    {
        while(num%counter==0 & den%counter==0)
        {
            num=(num/counter);
            den=(den/counter);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    for(int counter=2;counter<num;counter++)
    {
        while(num%counter==0 & den%counter==0)
        {
            num=(num/counter);
            den=(den/counter);
        }
    }
}    
cout<<num<<"/"<<den;     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function must return an object of type "fraction".

If you only want to print some value in a function, just define the return type as void.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not return anything. Use a return statement (such as `return 10` with the value being a `fraction` as you declared) or change your function to void (if it shouldn't return anything).